# How do I add a number suffix to my script? K thousands, M million

Tags: pine-script

Tradingview by default shows volume numbers as (K) Thousands and (M) Millions. How do I add this to a custom script I created?

For example, if I see Net Volume as 1740654.0000 on a bar, I would prefer it shows as 1.74M instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`study`'s `precision` with value 0 will help: 
https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_study

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", precision=0)
plot(volume)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!!

Comment: To make this work in Pine V4 you need to use the `format` parameter with the `format.volume` constant: `study("Your study", format = format.volume)`. In V4 the suffix is not tied to the `precision` parameter, you can use any value.

Answer (score 2):

In Pine Script v4 I was able to format the numbers in that way using the `format` argument of the `study` function.

From the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study):

> **format (const string)** type of formatting study values on the price axis. Possible values are: `format.inherit`, `format.price`, `format.volume`. Default is `format.inherit`.

```
//@version=4
study("My indicator", format=format.volume)
```